# Silverlight DataGrid: Hiding columns using VisualStateManager

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, show-hide

Is it possible to hide a column of a datagrid, without using codebehind?
E.g. by using the `VisualStateManager`?

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:data="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"
x:Class="Buttons.MainPage"
Width="640" Height="480">

<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Width="624" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,8,0" >
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="EditStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly" />
            <VisualState x:Name="Edit">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ShownInEditMode" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <data:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding BBRNumbers}">
        <data:DataGrid.Columns>
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="AlwaysShown" Width="80" Binding="{Binding Municipality}" />
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="ShownInEditMode" Width="73" Binding="{Binding Estate}" Visibility="Collapsed" />
        </data:DataGrid.Columns>
    </data:DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

Calling the following should then hide the column, but this doesnt work.

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Edit", false);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to come up with a simple solution to this as yet.  However its only fair that I at least tell you why this isn't working.   In order to animate a property the property needs to be `DependencyProperty`.  The `Visibility` property of the `DataGridColumn` is not a `DependencyProperty`, hence it does not animate.

Comment: Thanks for the input, makes sence. THe solution ive been working with, is to inherate the DataGrid an implement a DependencyProperty which can control the visibilty of the columns. Ill get around posting this solution later. If you got a better one, please let me know :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting column width = 0

Answer (score 0):

You can either subclass DataGrid or create an attached property to toggle Visibility. However, unlike Opacity, you can't really 'animate' Visibility unless you enable FluidLayout in the VisualStateManager.

For more info regarding the fluid UI, please take a look at http://www.microsoft.com/design/toolbox/tutorials/fluidui/