# How to Dynamically change Datagrid Columns in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, binding, datagrid

Using the WPF DataGrid, I would like be able to change the columns displayed in xaml based on a property on the ViewModel.

The Idea is simply to change the set of Columns based on a property on the ViewModel. The various Views have columns in different combinations and all in different orders.

This should be trivial I thought but I can not find examples of where this has been done before

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

At it's simplest:

**Xaml**

```
<Window 
x:Class="Sample.MainWindow" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 


Title="MainWindow" 
Height="350" 
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
Width="700">
<Window.Resources>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>

    <DataGrid
        x:Name="grid"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False">

        <!-- If Mode = City then 
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="City" Binding="{Binding FavouriteCity}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        -->

        <!-- If Mode = Colour then -->
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Colour" Binding="{Binding FavouriteColour}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code**

```
namespace Sample {
public partial class MainWindow: INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public string Mode { get; set; }

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();


        Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>()
        {       new Person("John","Yellow","Paris"),
                new Person("Anne","Green","Lagos"),
                new Person("James","Pink","Brussels")
        };
        Mode = "City";
        OnPropertyChanged("Persons");
        OnPropertyChanged("Mode");
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class Person 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FavouriteColour { get; set; }
    public string FavouriteCity { get; set; }

    public Person(string name, string favouriteColour, string favouriteCity)
    {
        Name = name;
        FavouriteColour = favouriteColour;
        FavouriteCity = favouriteCity;
    }    }    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches to this I am sure, but the first thing I thought of was the VisualStateManager. See the MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager(v=vs.110).aspx). You might start by reading the remarks at the bottom of that page - excerpted:

> The VisualStateManager enables you to specify states for a control, the appearance of a control when it is in a certain state, and when a control changes states.

A caveat here is that I have not actually used the VSM yet; I merely came across it while answering another person's question. You may find his question to be an instructive example: [Changing GridView Item height using VSM Triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840317/changing-gridview-item-height-using-vsm-triggers/31844325#31844325)

The description of this class' purpose matches your use case though, and your implementation seems like a relatively straightforward extension of VSM examples.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried but I get an error  This does not compile as a Storyboard does not like a DataGrid Element? It says it's an invalid type

Comment: Someone else was trying to do the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447690/silverlight-datagrid-hiding-columns-using-visualstatemanager but they ran into limitations controlling the visibility of columns. See the answers and comments on that thread for ideas. There may be an easier way to go though than using the VSM.